# How to populate (append) list in Python with elements, that appear multiple of 2 times

Tags: python, list, append

Let's say I have a list of of list of 2 elements `[[1 , 2], ...]` in Python. Now I need to get something like this:

`[2, 2] [2, 3] [3, 4] [3, 5] [3, 6] [3, 7]`

Second element always goes up by 1, first element too, but occurs 2^n (n>=1) times, before going up.

So next will be 8 lists with first element 4, which occurs 8 times, second element of the lists will go up from 8 to 15.

Comment: Are you trying to modify an existing list which can be however long and have whatever numbers in it, making additions to the starting values according to the pattern you specified, and not lengthening the total list? Or are you trying to extend construct of the list pattern above for an arbitrary specified length?

Comment: I have some list and now try to add values with specified pattern. I think your second statement suits here more.

Comment: Does each add only operate on the last element of the list? So if your starting list has 5 sub-lists, the algorithm should ignore the first four elements and extend the pattern based only on the last element?

Comment: Exactly, algo should look for the last existing element in the list and apply pattern according with values in it. [2,4] last element in list. Then next would be [3,5] [3,6]... [4,7][4,8][4,9][4,10]...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try nested `for` loops like below

```
def fn(n, x):
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        for j in range(2**(i-1), 2**i):
            x.append([i, j])
    return(x)
```

or

```
from math import log2,ceil
def fn(n,x): 
    [x.append([ceil(log2(i)),i-1]) for i in range(3,2**n+1)]
    return(x)
```

such that

```
>>> fn(3, [[1,2]])
[[1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6], [3, 7]]

>>> fn(4, [[1,2]])
[[1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6], [3, 7], [4, 8], [4, 9], [4, 10], [4, 11], [4, 12], [4, 13], [4, 14], [4, 15]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a fun homework.

If you intend a function with an output like this:
[[1, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6], [3, 7], [4, 8], [4, 9], [4, 10]]

then this

```
def populate(n):
    left=1
    right=1
    temp=right*2
    output=[]
    for i in range(0,n):
        output.append([left,right])
        right+=1
        if(right==temp):
            left+=1
            temp=right*2
    return output
```

is one of plenty ways to do it.

If you meant starting with a list and n something like this should work:

```
def populate(inputlist,n):
    left=inputlist[len(inputlist)-1][0]+1
    right=inputlist[len(inputlist)-1][1]+1
    temp=right*2
    for i in range(0,n):
        inputlist.append([left,right])
        right+=1
        if(right==temp):
            left+=1
            temp=right*2
    return inputlist
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from math import log
initial_list = [[1,2]]
def extend_pattern(initial_list,n):
    last_sublist = initial_list[-1]
    first_element = last_sublist[0]
    for i in range(n):
        last_sublist = list(last_sublist)
        if i != 0:
            last_sublist[1] += 1
        last_sublist[0] = first_element + int(log(i+2,2))
        initial_list.append(last_sublist)
extend_pattern(initial_list,10)
print(initial_list)       
#[[1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6], [3, 7], [4, 8], [4, 9], [4, 10], [4, 11]]
```